# Codex vs Chapter Approved

Tags: warhammer-40k

I am finally getting around to doing my Death Guard in Warhammer 40k.  In the Dark Imperium, the Lord of Contagion, was listed at 137 points, in the Codex it is listed at 120 points, but in Chapter Approved it is 100 points.

There are no [corresponding errata](https://www.warhammer-community.com/faqs/) for Dark Imperium and the Codex for adjusting the points.  Now, chapter approved is after Dark Imperium of course, and I assume that it is also after the Codex, so should the point value listed in chapter approved be used?

This would apply to more than just the Lord of Contagion of course.  And, how would you determine when chapter approved supersedes the codex; eg. the Tau codex (which came out after chapter approved)?

Following that, how would someone find out chapter approved changes if there is none listed for the specific codex, without purchasing the book?  Seems rather schmuckish for GW to expect you to ALWAYS purchase chapter approved for updated points and rules

Comment: Regarding your last comment: Getting one book a year to balance the game isn't a terribly steep price to pay, and honestly is a vast improvement over hoping for a new codex entire.

Answer (score 3):

The codex is law.

It's expected you follow the codex if it's available, otherwise the Index (with many races on it), otherwise the rulebook (if datas specific to an army are in it), otherwise previous codex, rinse and repeat.

Chapter approved are, like erratas, supplementary materials aimed to balance the game. Sadly, Chapter approved can be outdated. If your codex/index is more recent than the Chapter approved, the codex's price is the right one, otherwise it's Chapter approved.

If you do not own the Chapter approved and play in tournaments or whatever, they should be able to give you the correct prices for the units you want to play.

About the "GW are schmucks", they are a business company trying to make money out of your hobby. To do so they have to make it balanced (not funny when someone stomp you because his army is strictly better than your army), they have to make new releases often, and a lot of other things.

By releasing a lot of new things, they have to make sure it's balanced, why not make profits of it?

Also, Chapter approved ends up in erratas and in reprint, usually.

EDIT : Death Guard Codex released in September 2017, Chapter Approved released in December 2017, therefore Chapter Approved's rules should be used, if any. In your example the price tag should be 100. I also went to my local store and they assured me that if it's printed in your Codex and you do not own chapter approved, you can use your Codex's pricetag.

Comment: Yes, the codex is law, until there are errata updating/modifying it.  The last sentence just reiterates my question ... there are no corresponding errata for the codex reflecting the changes in chapter approved

Comment: If nothing is in the chapter approved, you should be fine. If you could say when your codex was printed and when the last chapter approved that talked of your army was printed, you might get a more refined answer.

Comment: So, the part of the question saying 'in Chapter Approved' and explicitly saying which codex I am looking at is not enough? At this point in time there is only 1.  And the 'when printed' is precisely the root cause of this question

Comment: Updated, thought a new chapter approved was already released.

Comment: Chapter Approved 2018 just came out a week ago. Points may have been updated again!